# Visibility of input tag not changing with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

When clicking on the search icon () the input's visibility (`type="text"`) does not change even though it has been specified in the JS code.

```js
var searchIcon = document.getElementById("search-icon"); // the search icon
var searchBox_input = document.getElementById("search-box");
searchIcon.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if(searchBox_input.style.visibility == "hidden") {
        searchBox_input.style.visibility = "visible";
    } else if(searchBox_input.style.visibility == "visible") {
        searchBox_input.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
});
```

```css
#search-box {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    top: 0px;
    left: 120px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 130px;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

#search-box:hover {
    border: 2px solid darkgrey;
}

#search-icon {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 80px;
}

#search-icon:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="taskbar">
        <div id="start" class="btn">MyOS</div>
        <div id="search">
            <div id="try"><i id="search-icon"></i><input type="text" placeholder="Type here to search" id="search-box"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Why? How do I fix it?

Comment: it's not `visibility` it's `display`

Comment: @SamridhTuladhar , it is still not working even with `display: none` and `display: block;`

Comment: `Element.style` only returns the inline style of the element I think, and since it doesn't have any, it's returning "".

Comment: You could remove the second 'if'-condition, it should work then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `window.getComputedStyle(searchBox_input).visibility` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle))

```js
var searchIcon = document.getElementById("search-icon"); // the search icon
var searchBox_input = document.getElementById("search-box");
searchIcon.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if(window.getComputedStyle(searchBox_input).visibility == "hidden") {
        searchBox_input.style.visibility = "visible";
    } else if(window.getComputedStyle(searchBox_input).visibility == "visible") {
        searchBox_input.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

The `.style` property only contains the styles that have been defined on the element *itself*, not the styles the element has inherited through its CSS class or ID.

Therefore, `searchBox_input.style.visibility` is `""` at the start. You can then override this with your value, which then takes precedence over what has been defined in the CSS.

In short, CSS definitions are fixed. You do not change them with JS code like this. You can only define overrides.

A tiny change to your if/else accommodates the situation:

```js
var searchIcon = document.getElementById("search-icon");
var searchBox_input = document.getElementById("search-box");

searchIcon.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if(searchBox_input.style.visibility == "visible") {
        searchBox_input.style.visibility = "hidden";
    } else {
        searchBox_input.style.visibility = "visible";     // when it's still "", it also goes here
    }
});
```

```css
#search-box {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  top: 0px;
  left: 120px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 130px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

#search-box:hover {
  border: 2px solid darkgrey;
}

#search-icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 80px;
}

#search-icon:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="taskbar">
  <div id="start" class="btn">MyOS</div>
  <div id="search">
    <div id="try"><i id="search-icon"></i><input type="text" placeholder="Type here to search" id="search-box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Overall I would recommend defining an `invisible` CSS class like `.invisible { visibility: hidden; }` and toggling that class in JS code ([via `classList.toggle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)), instead of adding and removing actual CSS definitions.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the style property, use `getComputedStyle(searchBox_input)`. Otherwise, as you can easily see logging `searchBox_input.style.visibility`, the value is empty (`""`):

```js
var searchIcon = document.getElementById("search-icon"); // the search icon
var searchBox_input = document.getElementById("search-box");

style1 = window.getComputedStyle(searchBox_input),

searchIcon.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if(style1.visibility == "hidden") {
        searchBox_input.style.visibility = "visible";
    } else if(style1.visibility == "visible") {
        searchBox_input.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
});
```

```css
#search-box {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    top: 0px;
    left: 120px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 130px;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

#search-box:hover {
    border: 2px solid darkgrey;
}

#search-icon {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 80px;
}

#search-icon:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="taskbar">
        <div id="start" class="btn">MyOS</div>
        <div id="search">
            <div id="try"><i id="search-icon"></i><input type="text" placeholder="Type here to search" id="search-box"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var searchIcon = document.getElementById("search-icon"); // the search icon
var searchBox_input = document.getElementById("search-box");
searchIcon.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if(searchBox_input.style.visibility == "visible") {
        searchBox_input.style.visibility = "hidden";
    } else{
        searchBox_input.style.visibility = "visible";
    }
});
```

```css
#search-box {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    top: 0px;
    left: 120px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 130px;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

#search-box:hover {
    border: 2px solid darkgrey;
}

#search-icon {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 80px;
}

#search-icon:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="taskbar">
        <div id="start" class="btn">MyOS</div>
        <div id="search">
            <div id="try"><i id="search-icon"></i><input type="text" placeholder="Type here to search" id="search-box"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

if you change like above code, you can change textbox visibility.